# Valid memory address in Python

Tags: python, validation, integer

I am looking for suggestions of improving this function to check whether a memory address is appropriate or not.

```
def isweird(addr, cpu_name):
    """Check if a memory address is weird
    Args:
        addr (str): a memory address
        cpu_name (str): cpu name
    Returns:
        bool: True if the address is weird
    """
    if not isinstance(addr, six.string_types):
        raise Exception('The memory address must be a string.')

    if addr == '0x0':
        return True

    addr = addr.lower()

    # Strip leading zeroes
    addr = addr[2:].lstrip('0')

    if utils.is64(cpu_name):
        if len(addr) <= 8:
            val = int(addr, 16)
            if val <= (1 << 16):  # val <= 0xffff (ie: first 64k)
                return True
        elif addr.startswith('ffffffff'):
            addr = addr[8:]  # 8 == len('ffffffff')
            val = int(addr, 16)
            if val >= ((1 << 32) - (1 << 16)):  # val >= 0xffffffffffff0000 (ie: last 64k)
                return True
    else:
        val = int(addr, 16)
        if val <= 1 << 16:  # val <= 0xffff (ie: first 64k)
            return True
        if val >= ((1 << 32) - (1 << 16)):  # val >= 0xffff0000 (ie: last 64k)
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this code:

> ```
> if len(addr) <= 8:
>     val = int(addr, 16)
>     if val <= (1 << 16):  # val <= 0xffff (ie: first 64k)
>         return True
> elif addr.startswith('ffffffff'):
>     addr = addr[8:]  # 8 == len('ffffffff')
>     val = int(addr, 16)
>     if val >= ((1 << 32) - (1 << 16)):  # val >= 0xffffffffffff0000 (ie: last 64k)
>         return True
> ```

You can replace the inner `if` statements with `return` statements:

```
if len(addr) <= 8:
    val = int(addr, 16)
    return val <= (1 << 16)  # val <= 0xffff (ie: first 64k)
elif addr.startswith('ffffffff'):
    addr = addr[8:]  # 8 == len('ffffffff')
    val = int(addr, 16)
    return val >= ((1 << 32) - (1 << 16))  # val >= 0xffffffffffff0000 (ie: last 64k)
```

This is possible because if these conditions are false,
the execution will reach the `return False` at the end of the function.
The reason to rewrite this way is so that the reader doesn't have to follow the execution path until the end of the function,
he can know on these lines that no further statements will be executed,
the return value is already decided at these points.

---

Some of the comments are incorrect and misleading:

> ```
> if val <= (1 << 16):  # val <= 0xffff (ie: first 64k)
>
> if val >= ((1 << 32) - (1 << 16)):  # val >= 0xffffffffffff0000 (ie: last 64k)
> ```

`1 << 16` is `0x10000`, not `0xffff`.

`(1 << 32) - (1 << 16)` is `0xffff0000`, not `0xffffffffffff0000`.

---

Following [the naming conventions of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
the function `isweird` should be named `is_weird` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use binary operators when you can use numbers. Take:

```
if val <= (1 << 16):  # val <= 0xffff (ie: first 64k)
```

This can just be:

```
if val <= 0xffff:
```

This allows you to remove the comments, whilst keeping clarity for users to understand what numbers you are using.

Comment: "boolean operators" I guess you meant "binary operators"

Comment: Minor correction, 1<<16 == 0x10000